# Closest point to a path

Tags: r, performance, spatial, rcpp, rcpp11

I have two sets of points, called `path` and `centers`. For each point in `path`, I would like an efficient method for finding the ID of the closest point in `centers`. I would like to do this in R. Below is a simple reproducible example.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 10000
x <- 100*cumprod(1 + rnorm(n, 0.0001, 0.002))
y <- 50*cumprod(1 + rnorm(n, 0.0001, 0.002))

path <- data.frame(cbind(x=x, y=y))

centers <- expand.grid(x=seq(0, 500,by=0.5) + rnorm(1001), 
                       y=seq(0, 500, by=0.2) + rnorm(2501))

centers$id <- seq(nrow(centers))
```

`x` and `y` are coordinates. I would like to add a column to the `path` data.frame that has the id of the closest center for the given x and y co-ordinate. I then want to get all of the unique ids.

My solution at the moment does work, but is very slow when the scale of the problem increases. I would like something much more efficient.

```
path$closest.id <- sapply(seq(nrow(path)), function(z){
   tmp <- ((centers$x - path[z, 'x'])^2) + ((centers$y - path[z, 'y'])^2)
   as.numeric(centers[tmp == min(tmp), 'id'])
})

output <- unique(path$closest.id)
```

Any help on speeding this up would be greatly appreciated.

I think `data.table` might help, but ideally what I am looking for is an algorithm that is perhaps a bit smarter in terms of the search, i.e. instead of calculating the distances to each center and then only selecting the minimum one... to get the id...

I am also happy to use `Rcpp`/`Rcpp11` as well if that would help improve performance.

My minimum acceptable time to perform this kind of calculation out would be 10 seconds, but obviously faster would be better.

Comment: What is the scale of your actual problem? What is `n` and `nrow(centers)`?

Comment: n is 10000, nrow(centers) is 1000000

Comment: What resources do you have available? OS, cores, etc? Also, the sample data only ever gives a single 'id'; in the real data do you have multiple 'id's getting returned for a single iteration? Lastly, your comment indicates nrow(centers) at 1M but the sample data has it at 5M which is it and what is your timing currently (on the sample data)?

Comment: I have a Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1, running on Intel Core i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz, 4GB RAM, 32 bit OS. I would expect only a single id for each iteration, never more than that...and yes the timing is on the sample data...as I would like the solution to be much more efficient than 10 seconds...

Comment: What is your current timing on the sample data?

Comment: If using `sapply(seq(100),function(z){` it takes 9.11 seconds, so linearly extrapolating the sample data which has 10000 it should take 911 seconds which is about 15 minutes 11 seconds...

Comment: Now doing the full list set took 952.15 seconds, which is 15 minutes 52 seconds

Comment: I get a speedup of about a factor 2 by substituting the line `as.numeric(centers[tmp==min(tmp),'id'])` with `which.min(tmp)`, achieving the same result. But I gather you need a speedup of 100, so I have 50 still to go...

Comment: Is your example, is `centers` representative of your true `centers` object? i.e. can we assume that for each `y`, a point exists at each `x`?

Comment: Yes each center will have an x and y value....

Comment: You misunderstand me - does `centers` include all `xy` combinations of your set of unique `x` and your set of unique `y`? i.e., like the output of `expand.grid`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this with `nn2` from the `RANN` package. On my system, this computes the nearest `center` to each of your `path` points in under 2 seconds.

```
library(RANN)
system.time(closest <- nn2(centers[, 1:2], path, 1))

#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.41    0.14    1.55 



sapply(closest, head)

#      nn.idx   nn.dists
# [1,] 247451 0.20334929
# [2,] 250454 0.12326323
# [3,] 250454 0.28540127
# [4,] 253457 0.05178687
# [5,] 253457 0.13324137
# [6,] 253457 0.09009626
```

Here's another example with 2.5 million candidate points that all fall within the extent of the `path` points (in your example, the `centers` have a much larger `x` and `y` range than do the `path` points). It's a little slower in this case.

```
set.seed(1)
centers2 <- cbind(runif(2.5e6, min(x), max(x)), runif(2.5e6, min(y), max(y)))
system.time(closest2 <- nn2(centers2, path, 1))

#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.96    0.11    3.07 

sapply(closest2, head)

#       nn.idx    nn.dists
# [1,]  730127 0.025803703
# [2,]  375514 0.025999069
# [3,] 2443707 0.047259283
# [4,]   62780 0.022747930
# [5,] 1431847 0.002482623
# [6,] 2199405 0.028815865
```

This can be compared to the output using `sp::spDistsN1` (which is much slower for this problem):

```
library(sp)
apply(head(path), 1, function(x) which.min(spDistsN1(centers, x)))

#       1       2       3       4       5       6 
#  730127  375514 2443707   62780 1431847 2199405
```

Adding the point id to the `path` data.frame and reducing to unique values is trivial:

```
path$closest.id <- closest$nn.idx
output <- unique(path$closest.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for this one! Reading up on RANN obviously led to studying _how_ the approximate kd-tree search works, which in turn led to the FLANN library then to nanoflann (a header only trimmed down FLANN) and using Rcpp w/ nanoflann which further trimmed ~10% off the nn2 time.It used Eigen Mapped Matrixes to the input data.frames with exact search.

Comment: Perhaps I am miss understanding the result...but what does the nn.idx and nn.dist mean? i.e. how does 44 relate to the relevant center id?

Comment: Actually figured it out...the first part should say `nn2(centers[,1:2], path, 1)`

Comment: @h.l.m - ah, yes, you're right - otherwise it treats it as a 3-dimensional problem. I've corrected the answer now. Note that the addition of an integer sequence `id` column is redundant since `nn2` returns, for each point in `path`, the index of the row of the closest `centers` point.

Comment: @h.l.m - to answer your previous question, `nn.idx` is an index vector indicating which `centers` point is closest to each `path` point; `nn.dists` gives the distance between these closest points.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an `Rcpp11` solution. Something similar might work with `Rcpp` with a few changes.

```
#define RCPP11_PARALLEL_MINIMUM_SIZE 1000
#include <Rcpp11>

inline double square(double x){
    return x*x ;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector closest( DataFrame path, DataFrame centers ){

    NumericVector path_x = path["x"], path_y = path["y"] ;
    NumericVector centers_x = centers["x"], centers_y = centers["y"] ;

    int n_paths = path_x.size(), n_centers = centers_x.size() ; 


    IntegerVector ids = sapply( seq_len(n_paths), [&](int i){
            double px = path_x[i], py=path_y[i] ;

            auto get_distance = [&](int j){
                return  square(px - centers_x[j]) + square(py-centers_y[j]) ;
            } ;

            double distance = get_distance(0) ;
            int res=0;

            for( int j=1; j<n_centers; j++){
                double d = get_distance(j)  ;
                if(d < distance){
                    distance = d ;
                    res = j ;
                }
            }

            return res + 1 ;
    }) ;

    return unique(ids) ;

}
```

I get :

```
> set.seed(1)

> n <- 10000

> x <- 100 * cumprod(1 + rnorm(n, 1e-04, 0.002))

> y <- 50 * cumprod(1 + rnorm(n, 1e-04, 0.002))

> path <- data.frame(cbind(x = x, y = y))

> centers <- expand.grid(x = seq(0, 500, by = 0.5) +
+     rnorm(1001), y = seq(0, 500, by = 0.2) + rnorm(2501))

> system.time(closest(path, centers))
   user  system elapsed
 84.740   0.141  21.392
```

This takes advantage of automatic parallelization of sugar, i.e. `sapply` is run in parallel.  The `#define RCPP11_PARALLEL_MINIMUM_SIZE 1000` part is to force the parallel, which is otherwise by default only kicked in from 10000. But in that case since the inner computation are time consuming, it's worth it.

Note that you need a development version of `Rcpp11` because `unique` is broken in the released version.

Comment: I like the sound of _something similar might work with Rcpp_ and would be up for that. You reckon it needs to go Rcpp (for `sapply`) proper rather than RcppParallel (for a different top-level function)?

Comment: `Rcpp` cannot `sapply` lambda functions.

Comment: Did you check the resulting indexes against the given sample? They aren't identical... ?

Comment: Ah, will do, are they by any chance perhaps just not in the same order ?

Answer (score 1):

This solution reduces processing time for the sample dataset by almost half that achieved by the RANN solution.

It can be installed using `devtools::install_github("thell/Rcppnanoflann")`

The Rcppnanoflann solution takes advantage of Rcpp, RcppEigen and
the nanoflann EigenMatrixAdaptor along with the c++11  to yield
identical unique indexes to the original question.

```
library(Rcppnanoflann)
system.time(o.nano<-nnIndex(centers,path))

##    user  system elapsed 
##    0.62    0.05    0.67
```

<sup><sub>* using path and centers *values* as defined in the original question</sub></sup>

To achieve identical results to the original sample the RANN solution needs
slight modification which we time here...

```
library(RANN)
system.time(o.flann<-unique(as.numeric(nn2(centers,path,1)$nn.idx)))

##    user  system elapsed 
##    1.24    0.07    1.30
```

```
identical(o.flann,o.nano)

## [1] TRUE
```

The working function of Rcppnanoflann takes advantage of Eigen's Map
capabilities to create the input for a fixed type Eigen matrix from
the given `P` dataframe.

Testing was done with the RcppParallel package but the kd_tree object does not have
a copy constructor, so the tree needed to be created for each thread
which ate up any gains in the parallel query processing.

RcppEigen and Rcpp11 currently don't play together so the idea of
using Rcpp11's parallel sapply for the query isn't easily tested.

---

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> nnIndex(const Rcpp::DataFrame & P, const Rcpp::DataFrame & Q )
{
  using namespace Eigen;
  using namespace Rcpp;
  using namespace nanoflann;

  // Matrix of points to be queried against.
  const NumericVector & Px(P[0]);
  const NumericVector & Py(P[1]);
  MatrixX2d M(Px.size(), 2);
  M.col(0) = VectorXd::Map(&Px[0],Px.size());
  M.col(1) = VectorXd::Map(&Py[0],Py.size());

  // The points to query.
  const NumericVector & Qx(Q[0]);
  const NumericVector & Qy(Q[1]);
  double query_pt[2];
  size_t query_count(Qx.size());

  // Populate a 2d tree.
  KD_Tree kd_tree( 2, M, 10 );
  kd_tree.index->buildIndex();

  std::set<size_t> nn;
  std::vector<double> out;
  out.reserve(query_count);

  size_t index(0);
  double quadrance;
  for( size_t i=0 ; i < query_count; ++i ) {
    query_pt[0] = Qx[i];
    query_pt[1] = Qy[i];
    kd_tree.index->knnSearch( &query_pt[0],1, &index, &quadrance);
    if( nn.emplace(index).second ) out.emplace_back(index+1);
  }

  return out;
}
```