# Points closest to an estimated path

Tags: r, performance

Similar to my previous question: [Closest point to a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321856/closest-point-to-a-path)

I would like to be able to find all the centers that are closest to a path. However some of the data is missing from the path, and I would like to do linear segments to interpolate between points to 'estimate' a possible path, and still find likely centers that would have been close to that 'estimated path'.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 10000
x <- 100*cumprod(1 + rnorm(n, 0.0001, 0.002))
y <- 50*cumprod(1 + rnorm(n, 0.0001, 0.002))

# original path
path <- data.frame(cbind(x=x, y=y))

# path with missing points/points every hundred
path.w.missing <- path[seq(1,n,by=100),]


centers <- expand.grid(x=seq(0, 500,by=0.5) + rnorm(1001), 
                       y=seq(0, 500, by=0.2) + rnorm(2501))

centers$id <- seq(nrow(centers))
```

Short of simulating millions of linear points between the given points in the path....I'm not sure how one would go about doing this...

To me its a bit like finding the intersection of a line and a matrix of cells...of sorts....but perhaps I'm miles off...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean to find all points that lie on the path within a certain threshold?

Comment: Divide the path into line segments.  For each segment, determine the closest point.  Loop over the segments using some version of apply.  It may be easiest to understand if you rotate the segment to be horizontal or vertical so the distance to the points is just the y (or x) coordinate.

Comment: If giving a threshold is the only possible way then yes happy to introduce a threshold value to the problem...but ideally not...

Comment: I wonder if `?mahalanobis` of any help here?

Comment: One way is to go with a simple interpolation by `approx(,n=n.int)` and use the nearest neighbor approach. One could then almost correct for the bias by pythagoras (adjusting distances between centers and interpolation points), making the error converge quite fast in `n.int`.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help:

```
## create data
set.seed(1)
n <- 10000
x <- 100 * cumprod(1 + rnorm(n, 0.0001, 0.002))
y <- 50 * cumprod(1 + rnorm(n, 0.0001, 0.002))

# original path
path <- data.frame(cbind(x=x, y=y))

# path with missing points/points every hundred
path.w.missing <- path[seq(1,n,by=100),]


## proposed solution
library(raster)

l <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(path.w.missing)), "1")))
r <- raster(extent(bbox(l)), res = c(0.5, 0.2))
r <- rasterize(l, r, field = 1)

## xy will be a matrix
xy <- rasterToPoints(r)

plot(r)
points(xy)
points(path.w.missing, col = "red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The package `marmap` does exactly what you need:

```
library(marmap)
bcenters <- as.bathy(centers)
out <- path.profile(path.w.missing,bcenters)

       lon      lat   dist.km  depth
2 100.0512 50.04129   0.00000 247451
3 101.2070 50.11430  82.87177 247450
4 101.3687 50.18730  95.33454 247449
5 101.5973 50.26030 112.81665 248453
6 102.6877 50.33330 190.48139 248454
7 103.2105 50.40630 228.37510 248458
```

The `id` is in the column `depth`. This function was coded to retrieve depth in a bathymetric matrix along a path. It finds all cells of the bathymetric matrix "bellow" the path (i.e. cells closest to the path) and outputs the value of these cells. By transforming your `centers` object into a matrix of class `bathy`, your column `id` is used as if it was the depth. Thus `path.profile()` outputs the `id` of the cells closest to your path in the `depth` column.

Here, you start with 100 points in your `path.w.missing` object. `path.profile()` gets you the id 
of the

```
nrow(out)
795
```

cells that are closest to this path.

Here is a plot of the `path.w.missing` data with the closest points overlaid in red:

```
plot(path.w.missing,type="o",cex=.3, lwd=5)
points(out[,1],out[,2], col=rgb(1,0,0,.8), cex=.3)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use the smooth.spline function (Fit a Smoothing Spline)

```
mx=path.w.missing$x
my=path.w.missing$y
s<-smooth.spline(mx,my)
plot(mx,my)
lines(s) #draw the estimated path
```

[image]

```
predict(s,1:10) #And now you can generate all the points on the estimated path

> predict(s,1:10)
$x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$y
 [1] 2.418294 2.904019 3.389744 3.875469 4.361195 4.846920 5.332645 5.818370 6.304095 6.789820
```

And you can use the Linear model to fit it.

```
> summary(lm(my~mx))

Call:
lm(formula = my ~ mx)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-12.772  -8.642   3.112   5.831  17.237 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -12.60098    3.46583  -3.636 0.000444 ***
mx            0.56579    0.02138  26.469  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.896 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8773,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.876 
F-statistic: 700.6 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

as you can see,p<0.05,so my and mx can fit as a line:

```
my=-12.60098+0.56579*mx
```

ggplot2 can draw this line easily:

```
 d=data.frame(mx,my)
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(d,aes(mx,my))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

[image]

assume that a line is `Ax+By+C=0` and the point is`(X0，Y0)`,point to the line distance：

```
|AX0+BY0+C|/√(A²+B²)
```

so in this case, 0.56579*mx-my-12.60098=0 ,A=0.56579,B=-1,C=-12.60098 ,it's easy to calculate the distance from point to line and find the closest point to the line.

Further more,if you want to find the closest point , remove the denominator √(A²+B²)  would not affect the sort,so,the optimization of the formula:

```
|AX0+BY0+C|
```

Result

```
> for(i in 1:2503501){
+ temp=abs(centers[[1]][i]*0.56579-centers[[2]][i]-12.60098)
+ if(m>temp){
+ m=temp
+ pos=i
+ }
+ }
> m
[1] 2.523392e-05
> pos
[1] 638133
```

Use the Rcpp to accelerate the program "test.cpp"

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int closest(NumericVector a, NumericVector b) {
  int length = a.size();
  double temp,m=10000;
  int pos=0;
  for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    temp=a[i]*0.56579-b[i]-12.60098;
    if(temp>=0){
      if(m>temp){m=temp;pos=i;}      
    }else{
      if(m>-temp){m=-temp;pos=i;}
    }
  }
  return pos+1;
}
```

Result(the Rcpp cost about 2 seconds):

```
> sourceCpp("test.cpp")
> closest(centers[[1]],centers[[2]])
[1] 974698
> abs(centers[[1]][974698]*0.56579-centers[[2]][974698]-12.60098)
[1] 0.0002597022
```

Comment: Thank you, but I had specifically asked for the linear estimated path between points, and secondly I am looking for points on the grid that are closest to that path, please see the previously linked question