# Finding closest coordinates and distance between two large data sets

Tags: r, distance, latitude-longitude

I have two data sets e.g. data1(58000 rows, house coordinates) and data2 (7500 rows, lake coordinates). I am targeting to identify the shortest distance from the closest lake for every house.

I have found the answer of similar problem but it is not working.
[r - Finding closest coordinates between two large data sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752064/r-finding-closest-coordinates-between-two-large-data-sets)

My expected answers are:
1. Find out the shortest distance from each house coordinates to nearest lake coordinates
2. Identify the lake that is the closest by ID/coordinates
3. Expected data frame:
  House ID.  Latitude  Longitude  Closest distance  Closest lake ID.

Comment: can you please provide [reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/3713478)

Comment: [finding_closest_coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752064/r-finding-closest-coordinates-between-two-large-data-sets), if Robert Hijmans is answering, it's probably working. Which code examples there did you try?

Comment: Finally, I am able to solve my problem with the code mentioned in my problem. Thank you.