# Find nearest point in second datset for every point in first dataset

Tags: r, data.table, geolocation, geospatial, nearest-neighbor

I have to data frames of points (lat+lon pairs). For each point in the first data frame, I would like to find the closest point in the second data frame. This question and answer gets me almost there ([Finding closest coordinates between two large data sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752064/finding-closest-coordinates-between-two-large-data-sets?rq=1)). The only difference, as suggested in a comment, is that *I would like to use geosphere::distGeo or raster::pointDistance* instead of what is in the answer. I have tried doing this (see code below), but get an error. How can I fix it? And what units is the `Distance` variable in? I would like it to be in miles.

Code - copied directly from aforementioned question, except (incorrectly) modified to try to get what I want.

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
                      6L, 7L, 8L, 9, 10L, 3L), 
               HIGH_PRCN_LAT = c(52.881442267773, 57.8094538200198, 34.0233529, 
                              63.8087900198, 53.6888144440184, 63.4462810678651, 21.6075544376207, 
                              78.324442654172, 66.85532539759495, 51.623544596), HIGH_PRCN_LON = c(-2.87377812157822, 
                                                                                                 -2.23454414781635, -3.0984448341, -2.439163178635, -7.396111601421454, 
                                                                                                 -5.162345043546359, -8.63311254098095, 3.813289888829932, 
                                                                                                 -3.994325961186105, -8.9065532453272409), SRC_ID = c(NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), distance = c(NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")


df2 <- structure(list(SRC_ID = c(55L, 54L, 23L, 11L, 44L, 21L, 76L, 
                          5688L, 440L, 61114L), HIGH_PRCN_LAT = c(68.46506, 50.34127, 61.16432, 
                                                                42.57807, 52.29879, 68.52132, 87.83912, 55.67825, 29.74444, 34.33228
                          ), HIGH_PRCN_LON = c(-5.0584, -5.95506, -5.75546, -5.47801, -3.42062, 
                                             -6.99441, -2.63457, -2.63057, -7.52216, -1.65532)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                              10L), class = "data.frame")

library(data.table)
library(raster)
library(geosphere)
#Euclidean distance 
mydist <- function(a, b, df1, x, y){
    
    #dt <- data.table(sqrt((df1[[x]]-a)^2 + (df1[[y]]-b)^2))
    #I couldn't figure out how to modify this correcly:
    dt <- data.table(pointDistance(c(a,b), c(df1[[x]],df1[[y]]), lonlat=TRUE))
    #dt <- data.table(distGeo(c(a,b), c(df1[[x]],df1[[y]]), lonlat=TRUE))
    
    return(data.table(Closest.V1  = which.min(dt$V1),
                      Distance    = dt[which.min(dt$V1)]))
}

setDT(df1)[, j = mydist(HIGH_PRCN_LAT, HIGH_PRCN_LON, setDT(df2), 
                        "HIGH_PRCN_LAT", "HIGH_PRCN_LON"), 
           by = list(id, HIGH_PRCN_LAT, HIGH_PRCN_LON)]
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error in .pointsToMatrix(p2) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2
```

Comment: Perhaps also update above with your error returned so when we get the same or different error...

Comment: Good point @Chris - I just updated.

Comment: And now, for something completely bogus, as to my confidence in what I'm saying..., perhaps instantiate setDT 1 & 2 prior to passing into `my_dist`, as I think you have an evn problem here with setDT(df2), as within the function env df2 is likely empty and might explain the seeming 'second point not found-ish' to calc a distance from error. Or, as usual, I'm completely wrong, and that would be more usual.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris. I am not sure either. I do know that the `dt <- data.table(sqrt((df1[[x]]-a)^2 + (df1[[y]]-b)^2))` code works (in case that is relevant).

Comment: I'm blind or something. What are `a` and `b` here and if not found in either df1 or 2, are they some sort of constants (perhaps shift) that went wayward?

Comment: I think they are just arguments to the function.

Comment: I'd suggest dropping `my_dist` approach and going with [Hijmans'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752064/finding-closest-coordinates-between-two-large-data-sets?rq=1) approach and answer, he did write `raster` after all and probably has a pretty good sense of these things. Note to note, the column swap there.

Comment: Above code doesn't search all combinations, but ony makes row wise comparison

Comment: Thanks @Chris - for some reason I didn't see that answer, but I should have looked more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c(df1[[x]],df1[[y]])` should be changed to `df1[, c(y,x), with=FALSE]` because `geosphere::distGeo` / `raster::pointDistance` expects a 2-column matrix of points. Also, it expects the points to be supplied as (longitude, latitude) - hence the (x,y) should be flipped to (y,x).

Using `raster::pointDistance`:

```
# Using raster::pointDistance
library(data.table)
library(raster)
library(geosphere)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

mydist <- function(a, b, df1, x, y) {
    dt <- data.table(pointDistance(c(b,a), df1[, c(y,x), with=FALSE], lonlat=TRUE))
    
    return (
        data.table(Closest.V1 = which.min(dt$V1),
        Distance = dt[which.min(dt$V1)])
    )
}

df1[, j = mydist(HIGH_PRCN_LAT, HIGH_PRCN_LON,
    df2, "HIGH_PRCN_LAT", "HIGH_PRCN_LON"),
    by = list(id, HIGH_PRCN_LAT, HIGH_PRCN_LON)]
```

[image]

Using `geosphere::distGeo` (same result as above):

```
# Using geosphere::distGeo
mydist <- function(a, b, df1, x, y) {
    dt <- data.table(distGeo(c(b,a), df1[, c(y,x), with=FALSE]))
    
    return (
        data.table(Closest.V1 = which.min(dt$V1),
        Distance = dt[which.min(dt$V1)])
    )
}

df1[, j = mydist(HIGH_PRCN_LAT, HIGH_PRCN_LON,
    df2, "HIGH_PRCN_LAT", "HIGH_PRCN_LON"),
    by = list(id, HIGH_PRCN_LAT, HIGH_PRCN_LON)]
```

Comment: Thanks! My goal is to get the distances in miles, which should be easy to do - are they currently in meters?

Comment: Yes. they are currently in meters. To convert to miles: `Distance = dt[which.min(dt$V1)]) * 0.000621371192`